# Send multiple arrays from ajax to controller(Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation)

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-ajax

When I send one array it works good, but only worked one time when the variable was not global but local inside the example_append() function when I made the variables global and there were multiple of them this error kept popping up
Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation

My view

```
 var dayids = [];
        var fromdateids = [];
        var todateids = [];
        function example_append() {

            var questionid = $('#offerDropdown');
            var day = $(questionid).find('option:selected').attr('id');
            var fromdate = $('#FromDate').val();
            var todate = $('#ToDate').val();
            var a = $('#' + day + '.FromDateSpan');
            var u = $('#' + day + '.ToDateSpan');
            $(a).html(fromdate);
            $(u).html(todate);

            dayids.push($(this).attr(day));
            fromdateids.push(fromdate);
            todateids.push(todate);



        }
        function ap() {
              $.ajax({
                type: "post",
                url: '@Url.Action("SelectAnswer", "Reservations")',
                ajaxasync: true,
                 data: { day: dayids, fromdate: fromdateids, todate: todateids },
                success: function (data) {


                },
                error: function (data) {
                }

            });
        }
```

My controller

```
 public ActionResult SelectAnswer(string[] day,string[] fromdate,string[] todate)
        {
 
 
            return Json(0);

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 var dayids = [];
        var fromdateids = [];
        var todateids = [];
        function example_append() {

            var questionid = $('#offerDropdown');
            var day = $(questionid).find('option:selected').attr('id');
            var fromdate = $('#FromDate').val();
            var todate = $('#ToDate').val();
            var a = $('#' + day + '.FromDateSpan');
            var u = $('#' + day + '.ToDateSpan');
            var c = $('#' + day + '.Day');

            $(c).append('<li>' + fromdate + '-' + todate + '</li>');


            dayids.push(day);
            fromdateids.push(fromdate);
            todateids.push(todate);



        }
        function ap() {
           
              $.ajax({
                  type: "post", 
                url: '@Url.Action("SelectAnswer", "Reservations")',
                  ajaxasync: true,
                  data: { day: dayids, fromdate: fromdateids, todate: todateids },
                success: function (data) {


                },
                error: function (data) {
                }

            });
        }
```

fixed

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).